# Solving a Permutations problem with Heap's Algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I'm working through some "Kata's" on CodeWars.com, and am stuck on the Permutations problem.

> Here is the problem: n this kata you have to create all permutations
> of an input string and remove duplicates, if present. This means, you
> have to shuffle all letters from the input in all possible orders.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> permutations('a'); // ['a']
> permutations('ab'); // ['ab', 'ba']
> permutations('aabb'); // ['aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa']
> ```
>
> The order of the permutations doesn't matter.

Here is my solution:

```
function permutations(string) {


const swap = (string, x, y) => {
    const stringArray = string.split('')
    const swapVar = stringArray[x]
    stringArray[x] = stringArray[y]
    stringArray[y] = swapVar
    return stringArray.join('')
  }

  const permutate = (k, arr) => {
    if (k === 1) {
      return arr
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        if (k % 2 === 0) {
          arr.push(swap(string, i, k-1))
        } else {
          arr.push(swap(string, 0, k-1))
        }
      }
      permutate(k - 1, arr)
    }
  }
  
  return permutate(string.length, [string])
}
```

When you pass in a single letter, it works fine. Two letters and it returns `undefined`. I've console logged the if statement block with the return and it should be returning the correct answer, but the result is still `undefined`. Considering it's getting the correct answer in the if statement and isn't progressing into the else block, I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - I was missing the `return` statement before the recursive function call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution

```
 String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
 return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + 
 replacement.length);}


var words = [];
var string = "lyes";


for(var i = 0;i< string.length;i++){

for(var j = 0;j<string.length;j++){
    
    var tempChar;
    
    if(i!==j){
        
        tempChar = string[j]
        var str = string.replaceAt(j,string[i])
        str = str.replaceAt(i,tempChar)
        if(!words.includes(str)){
            words.push(str)
            console.log(str)
        }
        
      } 
   }
 }

 console.log(words.length +" words found")
```

Comment: This does not find all permutations.  For your example of `'lyes'`, you only end up with six results, but there are 24 actual permutations of four distinct items.